R Tidyclust: Tune a K-prototypes model
I'm trying to tune a K-prototypes clutering model using the tidyclust framework. I'm modifing the guide at tidymodels.org to use K-prototypes instead of k-means. However, I get the below error when running tune_cluster() command.

Error in value[[3L]]():
! In metric: sse_within_total
Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double].

I understand that this error is because sse_within_total() expects numeric inputs. The help for sse_within_total() mentions that I can use a custom distance function. For example, I can use sse_within_total(workflow, dist_fun = cluster::daisy). This works fine if I use it on a workflow or a cluster_fit object. However, I'm stuck at how can I specify the distance function inside the tune_cluster() function.
Below is a reproducible example
library(tidyclust)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

data("penguins", package = "modeldata")

penguins <- penguins %>%
  drop_na()

penguins_cv <- vfold_cv(penguins, v = 5)

# spec1 is for a non-tunable model
kmeans_spec1 <- k_means(engine = 'clustMixType', num_clusters = 4)

# spec2 is for a tunable model
kmeans_spec2 <- k_means(engine = 'clustMixType', num_clusters = tune())

penguins_rec <- recipe(~ .,
  data = penguins
)


kmeans_wflow1 <- workflow(penguins_rec, kmeans_spec1)
kmeans_wflow2 <- workflow(penguins_rec, kmeans_spec2)

clust_num_grid <- grid_regular(num_clusters(),
  levels = 10
)

# non tunable clustering fit
kmeans_fit <- fit(kmeans_wflow1, data = penguins)

# this works without errors
sse_within_total(kmeans_fit)

# this also works
sse_within_total(kmeans_fit, dist_fun = cluster::daisy)

# However, this doesn't work
res <- tune_cluster(
  kmeans_wflow2,
  resamples = penguins_cv,
  grid = clust_num_grid,
  control = control_grid(save_pred = TRUE, extract = identity),
  metrics = cluster_metric_set(sse_within_total)
)

show_notes(res)


The main issue you are running into is that cluster::daisy() is the wrong type of distance function. What is expected of dist_fun() is a function where the first argument is a a data.frame of centroids, and the second argument is a data.frame of observations, for which we would want to find the distance to.
We can look at how Rfast::dista() works for this.

Thanks @EmilHvitfeldt, but how can I use a different dist_fun in tune_cluster(). I can't find a way to tell the tune_cluster() metrics argument to use a different dist_fun.

the distance is tied to the metric, so you could make a new matric with yardstick::metric_tweak(), and pass that new metric to tune_cluster()
